# WPF Using Image Control to dynamically view Online images

Tags: c#, wpf, image, web

**Situation**

I'm trying to use an image control in my program that accesses an online image by binding it to a property.

*XAML:*

```
<Image Source="{Binding TheImage}" x:Name="imgPic" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="113" Margin="14,89,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
```

Specifically, I'm binding to the return value of the searchMembers method (which returns an object) mempic contains a URL, and this mempic will change depending on which member is currently logged in.

*View Model:*

```
public Uri TheImage
    {
        get 
        {
            return new Uri(hillracing.searchMembers(Username).mempic); 
        }
    }
```

**Problem**

Neither this code, or a static link to the image actually works.

Here is the test image I'm actually using

[image]

wondered if anyone could tell em what I was doing wrong.

thanks.

Comment: The binding is evaluated only once, because the property does not notify about changes (by e.g. implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged interface). You should however be able to see the initial call of the getter by putting a breakpoint there.

Comment: You try binding directly the URL string. like <Image Source="http://i.imgur.com/aIf7B0P.jpg" />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WPF `Image` control is more sophisticated than you imagine... just use the `string` URI value as the `Image.Source` directly like this:

```
<Image Source="http://i.imgur.com/aIf7B0P.jpg" />
```

Or, if you want to data bind, do this:

```
<Image Source="{Binding TheImage}" ... />
```

...

```
public string TheImage
{
    get { return "http://i.imgur.com/aIf7B0P.jpg"; }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm doing and it doesn't work, that's why I tried to use Uri.

`public string TheImage
        {
            get { return (hillracing.searchMembers(Username).mempic); }
        }`

contains the dynamic url

Comment: Then debug your `hillracing.searchMembers(Username).mempic` return value.